# Gravity Forms plugin: How to use "gform_editor_js" action hook?

Tags: plugins, hooks, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a question regarding this action hook: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_editor_js.

I'm not sure where to put this action hook. Can I use this action hook in my child theme's functions.php to make a jQuery script available when the plugin is in edit mode?

.......

I placed the hook in the child theme's `functions.php` as below but it does not seem to be working. Have I missed something?

```
add_action("gform_editor_js", "my_jquery_function");

function my_jquery_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('mytest1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/mytest1.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mytest2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/mytest2.js');
}
```

Comment: What is `gform_editor_js`? That's no native WordPress hook...

Answer (score 1):

You can either place the code snippet in the theme functions.php file or in a custom functionality plugin: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users

Edit:

To enqueue custom scripts on the edit page you should use [admin_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) e.g.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_function' );
function my_jquery_function() {
    if ( rgget( 'page' ) != 'gf_edit_forms' )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script('mytest1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/mytest1.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mytest2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/mytest2.js');
}
```

Comment: I tried placing it in the child theme's `functions.php` but it's not working for me. See the edit above. Any comments on this? I haven't tried the custom functionality plugin yet.

Comment: check the revised answer above